# PHP - iterate trough arrays and set different keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have wrote PHP function in my Symfony project `returnAllPosts()` which returns all entity objects from table that are found.

I want to assign new array structure with different keys and put those values of every specific post after that and return new array result with predefined post **key-value** pairs.

But this specific code returns just first object not all of them? How I can get them all from foreach loop?

```
      $posts = $this->myService->returnAllPosts();

        foreach ($posts as $post) {

            $post = [
                'valueOne' => $post->getValueOne(),
                'valueTwo' => $post->getValueTwo(),
            ];

            $posts[] = $post;

        }
        return $posts;
```

Comment: Looks like you are overwriting $posts in every loop, with $posts = [$post];

Comment: You probably want `$posts[] = $post;`

Comment: Adding `$post` to `$posts[]` makes no sense, because the iterator will grow.

Comment: This still gets me back first one, not all of them? $posts[] = $post; @CBroe

Comment: Well that's probably due to the "recycling" of variable names. Name the variable that you are looping over, different than the one you want to return at the end.

Comment: Ahh, it was that. Silly me. Thanks @CBroe